# Unable to Run Apache Airflow 2.7.0 in Python3.8 environment . Getting Error

Tags: airflow

> werkzeug.utils.ImportStringError: import_string() failed for 'flask_caching.backends.filesystem'. Possible reasons are:

- missing **init**.py in a package;
- package or module path not included in sys.path;
- duplicated package or module name taking precedence in sys.path;
- missing module, class, function or variable;

Debugged import:

- 'flask_caching' found in '/app1/python/envs/airflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_caching/**init**.py'.
- 'flask_caching.backends' not found.

Original exception:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.posixemulation'

**But I have werkzeug library in my python environment and also tried to downgrade the version to test but same error**